# Convert a number to Barcode Ean 13 and save it into sql as image

Tags: c#, barcode

i'm new here. I'm trying find a tutorial which i can convert a number example 5201000001100 to barcode ean 13 and save it into sql as image.
I made a lot of research in internet but i didnt found for ean 13. I found only some fonts which can create my number to code39 or code 128.

Answer (score 1):

**IMPORTANT**

The EAN 13 code in your question, 5201000001100, is *invalid*.

The last digit is a checksum that is calculated from the preceding digits. It is used to check whether the reader has read the code correctly.

The valid checksum for 520100000110 would be 2, so the whole code should be 5201000001102.

Now onto the solution.

**Using a free library**

Just install this NuGet package:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Zen.Barcode.Rendering.Framework/

How to use:

```
Image codeImage = BarcodeDrawFactory.CodeQr.Draw("001234567890", 3, 3);
```

**Using a font**

You can use this EAN13 font:

http://www.fontpalace.com/font-details/EAN-13/

Install it on your machine, create an image from the text and save it to the database as a BLOB.

Also, as @DirkTrilsbeek suggested, **you will need to generate the checksum yourself**. Here is how you can do it:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_digit#EAN_.28GLN.2CGTIN.2C_EAN_numbers_administered_by_GS1.29

The checksum is the last digit of the barcode. You can generate it using the following function:

```
string appendChecksum(string code)
{
    var sum = 0;

    for(var i = code.Length; i >= 1; i--)
    {
        var d = Convert.ToInt32(code.Substring(i - 1, 1));
        var f = i % 2 == 0 ? 3 : 1;
        sum += d * f;
    }
    var checksum = (10 - (sum % 10)) % 10; 

    return code + checksum;
}
```

The input is the code, the return value is the code with the checksum appended.

**Using a commercial library**

Aspose also has this (commercial but excellent) library:

http://www.aspose.com/products/barcode/net

**Using this free project**

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10162/Creating-EAN-Barcodes-with-C

You'll have to extract the relevant part from the Windows Forms project but at least it is free.

Comment: I try it but it doesnt work. When i create a barcode my scanner cant scan it

Comment: @Dim111: when using a barcode font, you usually have to generate the checksum yourself.

Comment: I added two more suggestions, I hope one of them will work for you!

Comment: First one doesnt work second one you must pay for it

Comment: Have you tried generating a checksum as @DirkTrilsbeek suggested? I added the algorithm to my answer.

Comment: So, there is not a code or algorithm for EAN. Should i make the code my self?

Comment: The CodeProject article contains an implementation. I don't want to copy the code here because of copyright reasons but if you click on the link and search for `CalculateChecksumDigit` on the page you can find it.

Comment: I implemented the checksum algorithm for you, it is included in my answer. I hope this helps.

Comment: I've found the ultimate solution. Just use the NuGet package I linked to in the answer.

Comment: Another important thing I noticed is that the code in your question is *invalid* (the checksum is incorrect). Try using 5201000001102!

Comment: Well, great, thanks for the downvote. I did a lot of research for this answer and I have no idea why you downvoted it. What is so wrong about my answer that it deserved a donwvote???

Answer (score 0):

As stated already, you can find fonts which generate a barcode from a textual code.

You'll need to implement an algorithm though which converts your EAN code to some textual string which can be used by the font to generate the barcode.
An explanation of the algorithm can be found here: https://grandzebu.net/informatique/codbar-en/ean13.htm

Finally, I would not choose to store the image in the database, but the EAN13 code itself.  Once you have the algorithm described above, you can simply reproduce the EAN13 barcode by generating the code and printing it using an EAN13 font.

A few months ago, I've created a class which generates such an encoded string from an EAN13 code.  If you print that encoded string using an EAN13 font, a readable barcode should be printed.
You can find this little project on github here: https://github.com/fgheysels/Ean13

Comment: why the downvote ?  All info in this post should be correct, and if not, it like to know :)